# Efficiently removing x-bit from files in large directory

Tags: linux, chmod

I have a directory /some/dir containing millions of files and directories. I need to remove the X-bit for all file, but not from the directories.

The following works:

```
find /some/dir -type f -chmod -x {} \;
```

But I believe it spawns a "chmod" process for each file. That may explain why it runs for a long time.

Is there a way to do this in a more efficient manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides `xargs`, as Ljm Dullaart was mentioning, you can use:

```
find /some/dir -type f -exec chmod -x {} +
```

As a debug trick, you can see the generated command with:

```
find /some/dir -type f -exec echo chmod -x {} +
```

From the man page of [find(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) command:

> `-exec command {} +`
> This variant of the `-exec` action runs the
> specified command on the selected files, but the command line is built
> by appending each selected file name at the end; the total number of
> invocations of the command  will  be much  less than the number of
> matched files.  The command line is built in much the same way that
> xargs builds its command lines.  Only one instance of `{}` is allowed
> within the command, and it must appear at the end, immediately before
> the `+`; it needs to be escaped (with a `\`) or quoted to protect it
> from interpretation by the shell.  The command is executed in the
> starting directory.  If any invocation with the `+` form returns a
> non-zero  value  as  exit  status, then find returns a non-zero exit
> status.  If find encounters an error, this can sometimes cause an
> immediate exit, so some pending commands may not be run at all.  For
> this reason `-exec my-command ... {} + -quit` may not result in
> my-command actually being run.  This variant of `-exec` always returns
> true.

Comment: Thanks to both you and Ljm Dullaart. I had seen the print0 trick before, but I thought it couldn't work when the number of files was larger than whatever limit there is for arguments to chmod. It seems find is able to generate the file list in chunks which do not overflow chmod's argument limit.

Comment: `xargs` is doing the same. They are just alternatives. And only GNU find has that `-exec command {} +` option.

Answer (score 3):

Use `xargs` to limit the spawning:

```
find /path/to/base/dir -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod -x
```